# Dynamically loading webpack common chunks in browser (with requirejs)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to create a Webpack bundle with some "vendor" dependencies (React, lodash, ...) and use them in my web app.

The issue I have, is that I don't want to add my *vendor.js* file as a `<script>` tag to my page, but rather `require` or `import` it in some way.

I tried using *requirejs*, but an error keeps coming up saying

> webpackjsonp is undefined

Now, from what I read webpackJsonp is defined by CommonsChunkPlugin, which disallows loading scripts with `async` attribute.

**My question**: **how can I dynamically load dependencies (vendors.js, commons.js, ...) only when they are required**, while still using webpack?

More info: I use Typescript for my development, which loads modules using *commonjs* configuration (eg: `import {clone} from "lodash/clone"`)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You use es6 import. commonjs syntax is require

Comment: Yes, but I use es6 import in Typescript. Which translates to es5 upon compilation if i'm right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack built-in [code-splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) - `require.ensure` or `import()`.

Comment: This would mean I have to change my (typescript) source, correct?

Comment: @Nsevens yes. you should use dynamic import in your source code.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to for example `require(["app"], function (app) {...})` in my html, which would then load *vendors.js* as needed. As you would use shim etc in requirejs
however, this gave me the webpackJsonp is undefined issue